# How to hook up custom pagination to antd Table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, antd

I'm trying to hook up my own custom pagination into antd Table, but i can't

this is what i tried to do

```
<Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={data}
    pagination={false}
/>
```

and here is my custom pagination from material ui

```
<TablePagination
  rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
  component="div"
  count={data.length}
  rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
  page={page}
  onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
  onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
/>
```

how to link Material ui to antd Table pagination, after doing a lot of research i found the solution is to disable antd pagination then add my own component, but what i couldn't find is how to hook up the component.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to hook external paginations to `antd` as far as I know, One way around which I found to use material pagination is to alter table `datasource` in the table itself. Although I would not recommend you to use this approach as it's not a proper solution. You can try one of the following:

1) Use the **Simple Mode Pagination** component (https://2x.ant.design/components/pagination/#components-pagination-demo-simple) of antd which is very similar to the material UI in terms of the structure of pagination.

2) Change the inner HTML of antd Pagination using `itemRenderer` property. Example https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/pagination/demo/itemRender.md

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll keep looking for a solution as antd pagination not looking pretty, and i think there is a work around this issue

Comment: @sasharomanov I would not recommend you to mix 2 types of views `antd` and `material-ui` as it would complicate things unnecessarily. However, you have full freedom to design your component however you wand so I have added another way using which you can change the HTML components of `antd` pagination